# User-friendly Android photo viewer for folders on remote server

Tags: windows, android, photography, cloud-storage, server

I have a personal server PC (running Windows10) where I store my photos.
They are ordered by folders (according to date, event, etc), I want to keep this hierarchy to easily find my photos.

What is a user-friendly application that can I used to look at my photos from my Android phone?
I just need to be able to browse the folders hierarchy on the PC, and view the pictures.
A "read-only" mode would be ideal (so that other family members can view the photos without risking deleting them).
(Optionally, if short videos could also be played that would be great).

It is OK if I have to install an application on the server-side or pay a license/subscription fee if the solution is good.

Comment: What OS is running on the PC? Would a file manager which can deal with remote directories be acceptable? Must the app come for "free" (as in "fee beer", which might include ads – or as in "free speech"), or how much would you be willing to spend?

Comment: Thank you for your questions @Izzy, I added details to address them in the post. A file manager would be acceptable if it is very user-friendly (only need to browse photos), and safe (Android app cannot delete the photos on the server).

Comment: Thanks for the update! I haven't tried any, so just hints here: There's [Gallery](https://android.izzysoft.de/repo/apk/org.xdty.gallery) in my repo which claims to work with Windows shares, and there are [several network-enabled file-managers](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_fileman#group_156), some of which also can deal with images and have an image viewer bult-in, e.g. Solid Explorer or [Media File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pcvirt.Manager).

Comment: Can they access photos on a server over the internet (i.e even when not connected on the same local network)?

Comment: As I wrote, I have not tried them. And it might depend on the way you plan to access that server: via some Website (http/https)? FTP server? SSH? Some file managers can deal with the latter two. Some of those web services have their own apps. And apart from that, isn't this a different question? You asked about photos on your PC, on on "some server on the internet" ;)